# Blank page is showing laravel and vue

Tags: laravel, vue.js, webpack, laravel-vue, laravel-mix-vue3

**Info**

Using laravel and vue project

1. After installing **composer install** and **npm install** blank page is showing
2. Laravel 8, Vue **vue@3.2.31**, **PHP 8** and **ubuntu 20**
3. Project location /www/html/**project**
4. Start the project using **php artisan serve**
5. Network tab http://127.0.0.1:8000/ showing status 200 but in preview tab

**Error**

No warning and console error. Network tab http://127.0.0.1:8000/ showing status 200 but in the **preview** tab below error gives

```
There was a problem loading your site type details
```

**Code**

**Webpack.mix.js**

```
 const plugins = [
require('postcss-import'),
require('tailwindcss'),
require('postcss-nested'),
require('autoprefixer')
];

 mix
.webpackConfig({
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            '@': __dirname + '/resources/js'
        }
    }
})
.js('resources/js/project/app.js', 'public/js').vue().version()
.js('resources/js/_default/admin.js', 'public/js').vue().version()
.postCss('resources/css/app.css', 'public/css', plugins)
.postCss('resources/css/admin.css', 'public/css', plugins)
.sass('resources/css/admin/bootstrap.custom.scss', 'public/css')
//.browserSync('127.0.0.1:8000')

//mix.dumpWebpackConfig();

if (mix.inProduction()) {
 mix.version();
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
"private": true,
"scripts": {
    "dev": "npm run development",
    "development": "mix",
    "watch": "mix watch",
    "watch-poll": "mix watch -- --watch-options-poll=1000",
    "hot": "mix watch --hot",
    "prod": "npm run production",
    "production": "mix --production"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.2.20",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.0",
    "axios": "^0.21",
    "browser-sync": "^2.27.7",
    "browser-sync-webpack-plugin": "^2.3.0",
    "laravel-mix": "^6.0.0-beta.17",
    "lodash": "^4.17.19",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "postcss": "^8.3.11",
    "postcss-import": "^12.0",
    "postcss-nested": "^4.2",
    "resolve-url-loader": "^3.1.2",
    "sass": "^1.32.11",
    "sass-loader": "^11.1.1",
    "tailwindcss": "^2.2.19",
    "vue": "^3.2.20",
    "vue-loader": "^16.8.2",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.12"
},
"dependencies": {
    "@headlessui/vue": "^1.4.1",
    "@heroicons/vue": "^1.0.5",
    "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.3.4",
    "bootstrap": "^4.6.1",
    "formiojs": "^4.13.11",
    "install": "^0.13.0",
    "npm": "^8.1.1",
    "or": "^0.2.0",
    "vue-i18n": "^8.26.5",
    "vue-router": "^4.0.12",
    "webpack-shell-plugin-next": "^2.2.2"
 }
 }
```

I don't know what's wrong with this project, I tried deleting the node_modules and npm install but still got the same error, npm run hot also did not gives any error

Comment: try to go to http://127.0.0.1:8000/public, laravel's `htacess` redirects everything to `public/index.*`

Comment: same error @Nemoko

Comment: Turn on error reporting in laravel and see what error it returns

Comment: @MukkaramWaheed, ever figure out what the issue was?

Comment: There is no issue everything is ok, Someone added dd("There was a problem loading your site type details") on laravel site

Answer (score 0):

```
 const path = require('path');


 mix.js(['resources/js/app.js','resources/js/_default/admin.js'], "public/js")
        .vue()
        .postCss(['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/css/admin.css'], "public/css", plugins)
        .sass('resources/css/admin/bootstrap.custom.scss', 'public/css')
        .webpackConfig({
           resolve: {
             alias: {
               '@': path.resolve('resources/js'),
             },
           },
         };);
    
 if (mix.inProduction()) {
        mix.version();
 }
```

Comment: Can you give some details as to what you changed here and why? Thanks!